# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined?

Tags: django, pinax, django-settings

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
import sys

# Set up django
project_dir = abspath(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, project_dir)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"
```

I did that, and I still get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
  File "/var/lib/system-webclient/system-webenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/var/lib/system-webclient/system-webenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import cache
  File "/var/lib/system-webclient/system-webenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    cache = get_cache(settings.CACHE_BACKEND)
  File "/var/lib/system-webclient/system-webenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/var/lib/system-webclient/system-webenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 38, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined
```

It was a small script calling some django functionality, but it is telling me ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE issue.

What can I do? I spent my whole afternoon reading many posts....

Thanks for helping! This was my 1st time hitting it.

---

The traceback. It doesn't give raise our manual exception. It is giving the same exception as above.

*webclient/main.py*

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
import sys
path = '/var/lib/graphyte-webclient/webclient'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
sys.path.insert(0, path)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "webclient.settings"
raise Exception("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = " + str(os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]))

    .... other things
```

In *manage.py shell*

```
>>> from webclient.settings import settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name settings

>>> import webclient
>>> webclient
<module 'webclient' from '/var/lib/system-webclient/webclient/../webclient/__init__.pyc'>

>>> import webclient.settings
>>> webclient.settings
<module 'webclient.settings' from '/var/lib/system-webclient/webclient/../webclient/settings.pyc'>
```

**webclient/deploy/pinax.fcgi**

```
import os
import sys

from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from site import addsitedir

sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../../")))

from django.conf import settings
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "webclient.settings"

sys.path.insert(0, join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

**webclient/deploy/pinax.wcgi**

```
import os
import sys

from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from site import addsitedir

sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../../")))

from django.conf import settings
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "webclient.settings"
#os.environ["SCRIPT_NAME"] = "/natrium"

sys.path.insert(0, join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

[filesystem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0f6R.jpg)

Comment: Did you set up your project using the `django-admin.py startproject` command, or manually?

Comment: @bennylope I've been running this for about 1 year, so I don't remember. But I don't see a reason why not through command. Oh. It's Pinax, by the way. So it should be through command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the top, it looks like the path to your settings file is not in your system path:

```
path = '/path/to/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that too. Adding that piece of code again to my python script, I still get the same error. I enter python shell, and found sys.path does not have the new path I added.

It is a virtualenv environment, if it matter at all. I activated it when i ran the script.

Comment: In your main.py, can you enter the following Exception and see what the traceback shows? Is the environment variable being set appropriately? `raise Exception("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = " + str(os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]))` If it says: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = None` the environment variable is not getting set, and we have to verify the `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = ...` is in the right place. If it says: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = u"mysite.settings"` then we will have to further investigate why it thinks the environment variable is not set.

Comment: Thank you very much. It didn't raise our manual exception. I included the setup scripts, it said `webclient.settings.` I also entered the shell to import the `webclient.settings` and it is there.

Comment: To verify: change `path = '/var/lib/graphyte-webclient/webclient/'` to `path = '/var/lib/graphyte-webclient/webclient'` without the trailing slash. Verify that there is a `__init__.py` file in /var/lib/graphyte-webclient/webclient, and verify that the settings.py file is in there (you may want to delete settings.pyc if it exists). Check permissions on all of these files that the python executor can access them. For the raise Exception(...), that must be after it is set in the main.py, move it below the `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "webclient.settings"` line.

Comment: Thanks. I verified and it still didn't raise our exception. I edited my code above (main.py), and uploaded an image. I deleted `settings.pyc` and `__init__.pyc` and restart the server, and it loads back. So `pyc` is the latest. It didn't work.

Comment: Try this with manage.py shell: `from django.conf import settings`. If that is throwing the same exception, you may need to have django in your path as well. Do you know where django is located? Try adding the path to django with `sys.path.append(path_to_django)`.

Comment: Thanks. I checked shell and it imports without problem. I am pretty sure django is in the path already, because I can import django, and it shows `/var/lib/system-webclient/system-webenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django`  :( Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bummer, User007, sorry I couldn't figure it out. I would perhaps start with a fresh project and see if you can get it working from scratch, then move the source code over when you get the new one working.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using django 1.6 + 
the below code should do it for you

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/project/')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project.settings")
from django.contrib import auth
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```